# Variaveis css com valores vindo do banco de dados

Tags: css, banco-de-dados, variáveis

Estou desenvolvendo um website onde me vi na necessidade de trazer o estilo(cores) dos elementos do banco de dados. Isso seria moleza se fosse uma pagina pois (por relaxo) poderia escrever o `css` no `head` do documento e trazer as variáveis com os valores do banco de dados. Mas o website é grande e preciso utilizar um arquivo `css` separado e vincular as páginas que forem utilizar esses estilos, pois por questão de desempenho não me agrada nem um pouco pensar em escrever a mesma folha de estilo no `head` de cada pagina.

Dei uma pesquisada sobre o assunto e vi nomes de pré-processadores como: `PostCSS`, `SASS`, `LESS`, etc.

Como nunca vi nada sobre o assunto então queria saber se tem algum modo de fazer funcionar as variáveis vindo do banco (a linguagem que uso é o asp clássico), ou se só é possível com esses tal pré-processadores, e se, só funcionar com eles queria que me dissessem qual seria bom usar e se eles permitem trazer os valores do banco de dados.

Caso não tenha entendido minha pergunta ou ache que não está completa basta perguntar que estou estarei no aguardo para tirar as dúvidas. Desde já obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta importar o css como php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.php" type="text/css" />
```

No php adicione

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css");

//configura as variáveis

?>

//Saida Css

body {
background: <?php echo $cor_fundo; ?>;
}
```

Comment: Boa Felipe gostei da sua idéia, sabe me dizer se o content-type funciona no asp?

Comment: Não precisa mais achei aqui na net, não sabia que o `@import` pegava arquivos assim. Vou testar aqui e se funcionar coloco sua resposta como certa ok.

Comment: até me confundi kk, você está usando asp, mas é basicamente a mesma coisa

Comment: Cara tu me salvou brother kkk estava achando que ia ser um bixo de 7 cabeças e você vem me mostrar uma coisa dessas, o que eu precisava era pra asp mas como o conceito é o mesmo pra qualquer linguagem vou deixar sua resposta assim mesmo. Para quem quiser em asp o content-type fica assim `Response.ContentType = "text/css"`, o resto é igual.

Comment: hehe, aí sim, as vezes achamos problemas onde não tem